# What is the difference between $$ and $! when using /bin/bash -c

Tags: php, bash

I am trying to understand the "oneliner" in [this comment](https://serverfault.com/questions/205498/how-to-get-pid-of-just-started-process#comment182403_205563) by @sysfault:

`/bin/sh -c 'echo $$>/tmp/my.pid && exec program args' &`

I tried the following variations...

Different $$ inside and out:

```
/bin/bash -c 'echo $$ && exec sleep 5' ; echo $$
14408
29700
```

Same pid (but in background):

```
$ /bin/bash -c 'echo $$ && exec sleep 5' & echo $! 
[1] 8309
8309
$ 8309

[ 1 ]+  Done  /bin/bash -c 'echo $$ && exec sleep 5'
```

Different pid for $$ & $! :

```
/bin/bash -c 'echo $$ && exec sleep 5 & echo $!'                                 
6504
6503
```

Kill did not work:
/bin/bash -c 'echo $$ && (sleep 15 ; echo done)'
19063
Killed
$ done (echo showed up after the kill)

Same pid with access to the pid of the foreground process:

```
$ /bin/bash -c 'echo > tmp.pid ; sleep 10 ; echo $$ ; echo done ; echo $$;'      
28415 (instantly)
28415 (10 seconds later)
done
28415
$ cat tmp.pid 
28415
```

With this command I was able to kill the pid in another window before the sleep finished - preventing the last three echos from happening:

```
$ /bin/bash -c 'echo $$ ; sleep 30 ; echo $$ ; echo done ; echo $$;'               
23236
Killed
```

Context: Ultimately I want to start bash processes via php exec(), and wait for the result before continuing *and* save the pid so i can clean up in case the manual cancel button is pressed. There are 2 expensive processes i will deal with: one rsync and one git commit & push.

What is the best way to reliably get the pid of a foreground bash script that includes multiple commands (with ; > | or &&) ?

Comment: Consider using `proc_open()`, `proc_get_status()` and `proc_close()` instead.

Comment: This comment was really helpful for the php part of the question, Thanks! I consider to make a separate question rather than get this one moved as @glenn-jackman suggested.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`$$` is the PID of the **current shell**. When you use $$ in the `bash -c` script body, you get the pid of *that spawned shell*

```
$ echo $$; bash -c 'echo $$'; echo $$
6872
6987
6872
```

`$!` is the PID of the **last backgrounded process**

```
$ sleep 5 & echo $!; sleep 5 & echo $!; echo ===; pgrep -l sleep
[1] 7118
7118
[2] 7119
7119
===
7118 sleep
7119 sleep
```

When you do `bash -c 'echo $$' & echo $!`, you get the same pid printed twice because, for your current shell, $! is the pid of the backgrounded bash process, and inside the script body, $$ is the current pid of that same backgrounded bash process.

When you do `/bin/bash -c 'echo $$ && exec sleep 5 & echo $!'`, you get two different pids: $$ is the pid of the bash process and $! is the pid of the sleep process.

- I find this odd because you're using `exec` so it should be the same PID (the sleep process replacing the bash process)
- However you're using `exec ... &` so bash must first fork a **subshell** to run the backgrounded task, and then exec replaces *that subshell* with sleep.

---

The answer to your actual question is best answered by a php person, which I am not. You should flag this question to a moderator and request it be moved to Stack Overflow where more php people are bound to hang out.

Comment: I consider to post a separate question, but I posted this one here consciously, as I want to more deeply understand the details that you outlined. So, Thanks!